# Does this result apply for locally injective function?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Definition: **Locally Injective Function**
Let $F : ℝ^{r+1}→ℝ^{r+1}$ be a continuous function, and let $a∈ℝ^{r+1}$.
We say that $F$ is locally injective (or locally one-to-one) at $a$ if there exists a
neighborhood $U$ of a such that $F|_{U}┊$ is injective.

My **question** is:

We know that if $F$ is a full injective function then $ker(F)=(0,0,...,0)∈ℝ^{r+1}$. Does this result apply for locally injective function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. Consider $F(x_1,\ldots,x_{r+1}) = (\sin(x_1),\ldots,\sin(x_{r+1}))$ and take the neighborhood $U= B(0,\pi/2)$. Then $F$ is injective on $U$, but there are many other points where $F$ is the zero vector.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is negative. Indeed, let $F:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2,$ $F(x)=(e^{x_1}\sin(x_2)-1, e^{x_1}\cos(x_2)),$ $x=(x_1,x_2)\in \mathbb{R}^2$. Then $F$ is locally injective, since its derivative $F'(x)$ does not vanish for each $x\in \mathbb{R}^2,$  and at the same time ${\rm ker}(F)$ is infinite.